# Input each element of a list into a function in python

Tags: python, argument-unpacking

Suppose I have a list `l=[A,B,C,D]` and a pre-defined funcion (I am using `sympy.solve_linear_system(matrix,A,B,C,D)`. I want to evaluate the function without writing in A,B,C,D. I want to do it in terms of the list. Is this possible?

When I use Unpack (*list) it gives me A B C D and not A, B, C, D and the function has an error.

Comment: use unpacking, ie `*`. `sympy.solve_linear_system(matrix, *l)`

Comment: "When I use Unpack (*list) it gives me A B C D not A, B, C, D and the function ahs an error" Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can only possibly help with code that we actually see, and we can only help understand errors that we actually see.

Comment: @JakeMcNaughton please add the full traceback and the code which causes this error, so it can be reproduced. [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)